# MySQL INNER JOIN not working

Tags: mysql

Im trying to write this statement for a game ladder I am making. All the inner joins worked until I added the team names into the equation.

```
SELECT tblMatch.AttackingTeam,
       tblMatch.DefendingTeam,
       tblTeam.TeamName As AttackingTeamName,
       tblTeam.TeamName As DefendingTeamName,
       tblGameMaps.MapName AS MapName,
       tblGameTypes.TypeShort AS TypeName,
       tblStyles.StyleShort AS StyleName,
       tblMatch.AttackingScore,
       tblMatch.DefendingScore
FROM tblMatch
INNER JOIN tblGameMaps
ON tblGameMaps.MapID = tblMatch.MapID
INNER JOIN tblGameTypes
ON tblGameTypes.TypeID = tblMatch.TypeID
INNER JOIN tblStyles
ON tblStyles.StyleID = tblMatch.StyleID
INNER JOIN tblTeam A
ON A.TeamID = tblMatch.AttackingTeam
INNER JOIN tblTeam B
ON B.TeamID = tblMatch.DefendingTeam
WHERE LadderID=$ladderID AND (DefendingTeam=$teamID OR AttackingTeam=$teamID)
```

The error I get is

> Unknown column 'tblTeam.TeamName' in 'field list'

The database does have a table named tblTeam with a column tblTeamName. Maybe I just cant see the error???

Comment: Please run the following query and add the result to your answer: desc tblTeam.TeamName;

Answer (score 2):

You have already aliased `tblTeam` to `A` and `B`, so instead of using `tblTeam.TeamName` use either `A.TeamName` or `B.TeamName` as per your requirement.

Comment: Beat me to the punch - or in this case the `Post Your Answer` button!

Answer (score 0):

You have a column `tblTeamName` in table `tblTeam` and in `SELECT` you are calling `TeamName`

```
   tblTeam.TeamName As AttackingTeamName,
   tblTeam.TeamName As DefendingTeamName,
```

And what is need to give alias twice to the same column

Answer (score 0):

So why write the line

```
tblTeam.TeamName As AttackingTeamName,
```

perhaps that is the problem (CTRL-F then enter "tblTeam.TeamName As AttackingTeamName,")